# Actionscript can't call javascript from locally-saved html

Tags: javascript, actionscript

I try to perform calling of a javascript function from actionscript 3.0 thru
ExternalInterface.call().
I've seen a lot of **online** examples where the method works perfectly. But all **downloaded** copies of the examples don't work. Flash player can't call javasript due to the swf-html container security problems. I've already tried to set allowScriptAccess value from "sameDomain" to "always". It hasn't solved the problem.
PS: browsers: firefox 3.6, IE 7.0s; flash player: v10.0

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the folder that contains the SWF that you want to use ExternalInterface.call() from to your list of trusted sites.

Right-click on Flash Player, select "Settings...", select the Privacy tab, click on "Advanced...", go to the "Global Security Settings panel" on the page that opens up and add your folder to the list.

Or, click here:

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html